# How to change sprite's direction to diagonal if two movement keys are pressed simultaneously

Tags: javascript, canvas, onkeydown, onkeyup

I am trying to move a sprite using arrow keys. Below is the logic that SHOULD cause the sprite to move diagonally if two keys are pressed. However, that is not the case. It will only move in one direction a a time. Since I am saving each keyCode as a Boolean within an object property whenever I press a button, I would think that this should not be an issue, but I can't get it to work. I have also tried using an array to store these Booleans, and checking those values instead. No luck.

I am at my wit's end and would greatly appreciate some help. I've scoured stackoverflow and many different blogs on building 2d games, but but nothing that I try works.

```
var keyState = {};

window.onkeydown = window.onkeyup = function(e) {
  keyState[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';
  // checks for up and left
  if (keyState[38] && keyState[37]) {
    player.pos.x -= 2;
    player.pos.y -= 2;
  }
  // checks for up and right
  else if (keyState[38] && keyState[39]) {
    player.pos.x += 2;
    player.pos.y += 2;
  }
  // checks for down and left
  else if (keyState[40] && keyState [37]) {
    player.pos.x -= 2;
    player.pos.y -= 2;
  }
  // checks for down and right
  else if(keyState[40] && keyState [39]) {
    player.pos.x += 2;
    player.pos.y -= 2;
  }
  // checks for up
  else if (keyState[38]) {
    player.animation.y = 64;
    player.pos.y -= 2;
}
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the movement logic out of the event listener. Have the key event just log the current state of each key (up  or down) then in the main loop check the state and move the play as needed.

As I am unsure if you want the movement to be constant or only on the press I have included the option to change the behaviour with the constant flag `MOVE_ONLY_ON_PRESS` if true movement only when a press is first detected. So that no key strokes are missed I clear the key flag in the main loop.

The following is an example of how to interface with the keyboard for a game.

```
// global key log;
var keyState = [];
const KEY_UP = 38;
const KEY_DOWN = 40;
const KEY_LEFT = 37;
const KEY_RIGHT = 39;

// Player
var player = {};
player.x = 100;
player.y = 100;
const MOVE_SPEED = 2;
const MOVE_ONLY_ON_PRESS = false; // This will toggle constant movement or only on press

// from your code
window.onkeydown = window.onkeyup = function (e) {
    if (MOVE_ONLY_ON_PRESS) {
        if (e.type === 'keydown') {
            keyState[e.keyCode] = true;
        }
    } else {
        keyState[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';
    }

}

// in the main loop;
function update(timer) {
    // you dont need to test for the combinations (ie up left) when its just simple movement
    if (keyState[KEY_UP]) {
        player.y -= MOVE_SPEED;
        if (MOVE_ONLY_ON_PRESS) { keyState[KEY_UP] = false; }
    } 
    if (keyState[KEY_DOWN]) {
        player.y += MOVE_SPEED;
        if (MOVE_ONLY_ON_PRESS) { keyState[KEY_DOWN] = false; }
    }
    if (keyState[KEY_LEFT]) {
        player.x -= MOVE_SPEED;
        if (MOVE_ONLY_ON_PRESS) { keyState[KEY_LEFT] = false; }
    }
    if (keyState[KEY_RIGHT]) {
        player.x += MOVE_SPEED;
        if (MOVE_ONLY_ON_PRESS) { keyState[KEY_RIGHT] = false; }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update);

}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

**Bit fields.**

Another way to simplify the arrow keys is to set the first 4 bits of a number to correspond to a key, one bit per key, then it is easy to test for combinations of keys as each of the 16 possible combinations has a unique number. You Could map many more keys this way but it becomes a little impractical when you go to far.

This is how to set them

```
var arrowBits = 0;  // the value to hold the bits
const KEY_BITS = [4,1,8,2]; // left up right down
const KEY_MASKS = [0b1011,0b1110,0b0111,0b1101]; // left up right down
window.onkeydown = window.onkeyup = function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode >= 37 && e.keyCode <41){
        if(e.type === "keydown"){
            arrowKeys |= KEY_BITS[e.keyCode - 37];
        }else{
            arrowKeys &= KEY_MASKS[e.keyCode - 37];
        }
    }    
}
```

These are 8 of the 16 possible combinations

```
// postfix U,D,L,R for Up down left right
const KEY_U = 1;
const KEY_D = 2;
const KEY_L = 4;
const KEY_R = 8;
const KEY_UL = KEY_U + KEY_L; // up left
const KEY_UR = KEY_U + KEY_R; // up Right
const KEY_DL = KEY_D + KEY_L; // 
const KEY_DR = KEY_D + KEY_R; //
```

This is how you test for then

```
if ((arrowBits & KEY_UL) === KEY_UL) { // is UP and LEFT only down
if (arrowBits & KEY_UL) {              // is Up left down (down and right may also be down)
if ((arrowBits & KEY_U) === KEY_U) {   // is Up only down
if (arrowBits & KEY_U) {               // is Up down (any other key may be down)
if (!(arrowBits & KEY_U)) {            // is Up up (any other key may be down)
if (!arrowBits) {                      // no keys are down
if (arrowBits) {                       // any one or more keys are down
```

Comment: Nice perspective. In my situation though, I will need to check for combinations. This is because I need to change which part of the sprite sheet gets used when every direction is pressed. However, if I were using only four different directions, this would be fine. I can probably just add in an if statement checking for the reciprocal of whether multiple keystates are pressed at once, and then use an else block that runs what you've written.

Comment: @Azurasky I usually make the arrow keys map to a single value setting setting the bits 0-3 to map Up, Down, Left, Right. Then i can check for one of 16 possible combos or just mask a bit to see if the key is pressed. Eg Up bit 0 to set `keyMap |= 1` to clear `keyMap &= 0b1110` and if I want to test for UP,LEFT (bits 0,2) `if(keyMap === 0b0101){` or if(keyMap === 5)`  (0b is the binary number prefix and 0x is the hexadecimal prefix handy for working with bit fields)

Comment: Oh man, this stuff is hard to digest. I''m taking a look at some documentation on bit fields (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) and just now learned that calling .toString(2) on a number returns its binary representation. Your answer went from good to great after your edit! I am learning so much.

Answer (score 3):

You should explicitly set the object key values as booleans and you should toggle them in separate keydown/keyup handlers:

```
let keysdown = {};

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(evt) {
  keysdown[evt.which] = true;

  if (keysdown["38"] === true && keysdown["37"] === true) {
    console.log('up & left');
  } else if (keysdown["38"] === true && keysdown["39"] === true) {
    console.log('up & right');
  } else if (keysdown["40"] === true && keysdown["37"] === true) {
    console.log('down and left');
  } else if (keysdown["40"] === true && keysdown["39"] === true) {
    console.log('down and right');
  } else if (keysdown["38"] === true) {
    console.log('up');
  }
}, false);

window.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt) {
  keysdown[evt.which] = false;
}, false);
```

This logs all the correct key combinations for me.

Comment: It works. Your answer doesn't really help me understand why my code didn't work, though.

Comment: @Azurasky. Put forth the effort to be analytical! Examine the working code to see why it works. This will help you understand why your code is not working. ;-)

Comment: @markE The logic is flawed. Key events fire once per key press, hence key `down`, then `left` will fire two events, the logic will on the first event move down , and the second event will move down and left, then the key up will fire twice, releasing key `down` will add a second move left (because it is still flaged as down), and the final release will do nothing.

Comment: @markE I know that comment means well, but the reason that I'm here is because I couldn't understand how to do this properly. Seeing the correct code is great and all, but that's all it is, correct code. Edit: But you are right. I could have went a littttttttle deeper than I did in trying to understand it. I'll remember that for next time! :)

Comment: @Blindman67 I appreciate the explanation. I'll accept an answer in the mornin'... I'm both mentally and physically exhausted!

Comment: @Blindman67. Actually I was relying on the OP's comment that it works -- I didn't review the code (maybe I should have). I was just encouraging the OP to examine all possible learning opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you why your code doesn't work. If I replace the player-movements with console-logs, it works for me.

Although it's pretty primitive.

First separate the keystate-manager from the movement-logic.

```
var isKeyDown = (function(alias){
    for(var i=0, a=Object.create(null); i<256;) a[i++]=false;
    for(var k in alias) i=0|alias[k], i>0 && i<256 && Object.defineProperty(a,k,{get:Function("return this["+i+"]")});

    function keyStateHandler(e){
        a[e.which||e.keyCode] = e.type==="keydown"
    }
    addEventListener("keydown", keyStateHandler, false);
    addEventListener("keyup", keyStateHandler, false);

    return a;
})({
    //add some aliases for more readable code
    up: 38,
    left: 37,
    right: 39,
    down: 40
});
```

once, because the update-interval of the keydown-event is not reliable, varies between browsers, and is not sync with the update-interval of the brwoser wich will cause flickering.

Now create a main loop for your game, and take account for the timing. Although requestAnimationFrame aims for a constant framerate you may have lags, and you don't want to see your player move at different speeds during these lags.

```
var lastCall = Date.now();
function tick(){
    requestAnimationFrame(tick);

    var now = Date.now(),
        time = (now - lastCall) / 1000;  //time in seconds
        //because it's easier to think in terms like 2px/s 
        //than 0.002px/ms or 0.0333 px/frame
    lastCall = now;

    move(time);
}
tick();
```

now the actual movement:

```
//the speed of your player: it would be better if this would be 
//a property of the player than hardcoded like you did, or global like this
var speed = 2; // 2px/second
function move( time ){
    //accounts for varying framerates
    //opposite directions cancel each other out
    var dx = (isKeyDown.right - isKeyDown.left) * time,
        dy = (isKeyDown.down - isKeyDown.up) * time;

    //taking account for diagonals
    if(dx && dy) dx /= Math.SQRT2, dy /= Math.SQRT2;

    player.pos.x += dx * speed;
    player.pos.y += dy * speed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on skyline3000 answer I tried to make it work also in down, left and right. Appart from adding the other options I had to change **window** to **document** to make it work:

```
  let keysdown = {};

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (evt) {
    keysdown[evt.which] = true;

    if (keysdown["38"] === true && keysdown["37"] === true) {
        prota.moveUp();
        prota.moveLeft();
        // console.log('up & left');
    } else if (keysdown["38"] === true && keysdown["39"] === true) {
        prota.moveUp();
        prota.moveRight();
        // console.log('up & right');
    } else if (keysdown["40"] === true && keysdown["37"] === true) {
        prota.moveDown();
        prota.moveLeft();
        // console.log('down and left');
    } else if (keysdown["40"] === true && keysdown["39"] === true) {
        prota.moveDown();
        prota.moveRight();
        // console.log('down and right');
    } else if (keysdown["38"] === true) {
        prota.moveUp();
        // console.log('up');
    } else if (keysdown["40"] === true) {
        prota.moveDown();
        // console.log('down');
    } else if (keysdown["39"] === true) {
        prota.moveRight();
        // console.log('right');
    } else if (keysdown["37"] === true) {
        prota.moveLeft();
        // console.log('left');
    }
}, false);

document.addEventListener('keyup', function (evt) {
    keysdown[evt.which] = false;
}, false);
```